# JDBC resultset into java POJO with list member

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have two query and resultsets, in the below code I want to showcase that for a particular `userGroupCode` I have certain `userPreference` and `employee` associated with it. I have written the code below code to display the `userGroupCode` object:

```java
String query1= "SELECT ug.userGroupCode, ug.userGroupDesc, up.userPreference"
+ "FROM dbo.UserGroup_link ug INNER JOIN dbo.UserPreference up ON  ug.userGroupCode = up.userGroupCode";
```

| userGroupCode | userGroupDesc | userPreference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A100 | Finance | Mumbai |
| A100 | Finance | Bangalore |
| A200 | Supply Chain | Chennai |
| A201 | Marketing | Delhi |
| A201 | Marketing | Kolkata |
| A300 | Health | Indore |

```java
String query2= "SELECT ug.userGroupCode, ug.userGroupDesc, emp.employee_id,emp.name,emp.role"
+ "FROM dbo.UserGroup ug INNER JOIN dbo.employee emp ON  ug.userGroupCode = emp.userGroupCode";
```

| userGroupCode | userGroupDesc | employee_id | name | role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A100 | Finance | 101 | Foo1 | Developer |
| A100 | Finance | 101 | Foo1 | Team Lead |
| A200 | Supply Chain | 091 | Test1 | Manager |
| A201 | Marketing | 591 | User1 | Analyst |
| A201 | Marketing | 1001 | Boo1 | Scrum Master |
| A300 | Health | 1001 | Boo1 | Developer |

I have class `UserGroupMapping` like:

```
public class UserGroupMapping {
    private String userGroupCode;
    private String userGroupCode;
    private List<String> userPreference;
    private List<Employee> emp;
    
    //getter and setter
}
```

Another class for `Employee` is:

```
public class Employee {
    private String employee_id;
    private String name;
    private List<String> role;
    
    //getter and setter
}
```

In my stored procedure class I am calling these queries with the help of `jdbcTemplate.query()`;

```
String userCode = null; 
List<String> userPreferenceList = new ArrayList<>();
List<UserGroupMapping> userGroupMappingList = new ArrayList<>();
List<UserGroupMapping> userGroupMappingList1 = new ArrayList<>();
UserGroupMapping userGroupMapping = new UserGroupMapping();
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
Employee emp = new Employee();
UserGroupMapping userGroupMapping1 = new UserGroupMapping();

jdbcTemplate.query(query1, (rs)->{

    String user_group_code = rs.getString("userGroupCode");
    String user_group_desc = rs.getString("userGroupDesc");
    String user_preference = rs.getString("userPreference");
    
    if(userCode == null){
        userGroupMapping.setUserGroupCode(user_group_code);
        userGroupMapping.setUserGroupDesc(user_group_desc);
        userPreferenceList.add(userPreference);
        userCode = user_group_code;
    } else if (userCode.equals(user_group_code)) {
        userPreferenceList.add(userPreference);
    } else {
        userGroupMapping.setUserPreference(userPreferenceList);
        userGroupMappingList.add(userGroupMapping);
        userPreferenceList = new ArrayList<>();
        userGroupMapping = new userGroupMapping();
        userGroupMapping.setUserGroupCode(user_group_code);
        userGroupMapping.setUserGroupDesc(user_group_desc);
        userPreferenceList.add(userPreference);
        userCode = user_group_code;
    }});
    userCode = null;
    userGroupMapping.setUserPreference(userPreferenceList);
    userGroupMappingList.add(userGroupMapping);
jdbcTemplate.query(query2, (rs)->{

String user_group_code = rs.getString("userGroupCode");
String user_group_desc = rs.getString("userGroupDesc");
String emp_id = rs.getString("employee_id");
String name = rs.getString("name");

if(userCode == null){
    userGroupMapping1.setUserGroupCode(user_group_code);
    userGroupMapping1.setUserGroupDesc(user_group_desc);
    emp.setId(employeeId);
    emp.setName(name);
    employeeList.add(emp);
    userCode = user_group_code;
} else if (userCode.equals(user_group_code)) {
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setId(employeeId);
    emp.setName(name);
    employeeList.add(emp);
} else {
    userGroupMapping1.setEmployee(employeeList);
    userGroupMappingList1.add(userGroupMapping1);
    employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
    userGroupMapping1 = new userGroupMapping();
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    userGroupMapping1.setUserGroupCode(user_group_code);
    userGroupMapping1.setUserGroupDesc(user_group_desc);
    emp.setId(employeeId);
    emp.setName(name);
    employeeList.add(emp);
    userCode = user_group_code;
}});
userGroupMapping1.setEmployee(employeeList);
userGroupMappingList1.add(userGroupMapping1);

    List<UserGroupMapping> ugList = Stream.concat(userGroupMappingList.stream, userGroupMappingList1.stream).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())
return ugList;
```

The problem is that I want my output to be like :

```
[
    {
        "userGroupCode" : "A100",
        "userGroupDesc" : "Finance",
        "userPreference": ["Mumbai","Bangalore"],
        "Employee"      : [
                            "employee_id" : "101",
                            "name"        : "Foo1",
                            "role"        : ["Developer","Team Lead"]
                          ]
    }
]
```

After merging the two list I am getting the below output:

```
[
    {
        "userGroupCode" : "A100",
        "userGroupDesc" : "Finance",
        "userPreference": ["Mumbai","Bangalore"],
        "Employee"      : []
    },
    {
        "userGroupCode" : "A100",
        "userGroupDesc" : "Finance",
        "userPreference": [],
        "Employee"      : [
                            "employee_id" : "101",
                            "name"        : "Foo1",
                            "role"        : []
                          ]
    }
]
```

Could anyone please help me with few things:

1. How could I embed the role into the Employee object.
2. How can I merge the table based on userGroupCode and userGroupDesc.
3. I am feeling the code is not that performance optimised, How could I optimised this code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't use `rs.next` as the `JdbcTemplate` does that for you. Write a single query that contains everything and filter in code for duplicates. Or write a query that aggregates the results already so you can do that in a single pass.

Comment: I am using Sybase ASE as database, so it's not possible with one query. I have to create stored procedure for aggregate.

Comment: Why wouldn't that be possible with a single query? Just add another join in the query you use.

Comment: My bad! I used the wrong table. Both the tables are different and if I join them then duplicity which would be difficult to filter out.

Comment: Just order/group them and if you have a bit of a decent database you could using grouping to auto aggregate the recurring bits making it easier on the java side (or just use 2 temporary maps to store or create objects. Nothing difficult about either solution imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola,

You can group by using Map taking id as key and value as object ( to be aggregated into) . For example:

```
if(map.containes(key))
{
    get object from map and do Ops.
}
else
{
    1. Create new object
    2. Do set Ops on Object
    3. Add to map.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically have 2 solutions,

1. Write a query that returns all results with joins and do filtering in java, quite easy to achieve with 2 maps (one for the `UserGroup` the other for the `Employee`.
2. Write a query and aggregate the duplicates using `list` in the query itself.

```sql
SELECT ug.userGroupCode, ug.userGroupDesc, up.userPreference, emp.employee_id,emp.name,emp.role
FROM dbo.UserGroup_link ug
INNER JOIN dbo.UserPreference up ON  ug.userGroupCode = up.userGroupCode
INNER JOIN dbo.employee emp ON  ug.userGroupCode = emp.userGroupCode
```

Then use a `RowCallbackHandler` to achieve what you want (instead of a `ResultSetExtractor`.

```java
Map<String, UserGroup> userGroups = new HashMap<>;
Map<Integer, Employee> employees = new HashMap<>;

jdbc.query(query, (rs) -> {

 String userGroupCode = rs.getString("userGroupCode"); 
 String emp_id = rs.getString("employee_id");
 
 UserGroupMapping ugm userGroups.computeIfAbsent(userGroupCode,  {
    UserGroupMapping ugm1 = new UserGroupMapping();
    ugm1.setUserGroupCode(userGroupCode);
    ugm1.setUserGroupDesc(rs.getString("userGroupDesc");
    ugm1.setUserPreference(new ArrayList<>());
    ugm1.getEmployee(new ArrayList<>());
    return ugm1;
 });
 ugm.getUserPreference().add(rs.getString("userPreference"));

 Employee emp = employees.computeIfAbsent(emp_id, {
   Employee emp1 = new Employee();
   emp1.setName(rs.getString("name"));
   emp1.setRole(new ArrayList<>());
   ugm.getEmployee().add(emp);
   return emp1;
 });

 emp.getRole().add(rs.getString("role"));

});

return userGroups.values();
```

The above code will get all `UserGroupMapping` objects from the result including all the `Employee` instances. The temporary maps are needed to determine if record has already been shown.

Another solution would be to use `list` in your query and some `GROUP BY` statement to let the query do part of the aggregation. That way you could make it a bit easier to create an `Employee`.